# jquery animate and fadeIn/Out issues

Tags: jquery, animation

having a couple of issues with something i thought would be easy in jquery.

check the demo here - dead link!

firstly jquery fadeIn/Out not working in IE 6 or 7 (also text looks bad when fades in IE8)

secondly firefox/IE animation choppy compared to safari/chrome which is very smooth, why?

is there a better way to do this or a way to optimise the code?

would really appreciate any help - still getting to grips with jquery

Comment: I have tested on the PC in Chrome 8.0, Firefox 3.6 and IE 9.0 Beta and everything works smoothly in each.

Comment: thanks for checking, yes it is fine in those browsers (although little choppy in FF/mac) - but IE6 and IE7 fadeIn/Out does not work -tried a couple of the fixes i found online but still did not work

Comment: ahhhh unbelievable, now not working properly in IE8. Works if i go to the uploaded site but the same code does not work when i test it locally. did before. Also tried animating opacity which does not work and also tried setting the display and opacity using jquery rather than css when page loads. still no. i hate IE - please help me someone

Comment: It works for me in IE8, but not if I am in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer by asking again here [jquery fadeIn/Out IE problem - frustrating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680558/jquery-fadein-out-ie-problem-frustrating) . The problem was i had given my list item (li#about) the same id name as my div (div#about). IE does not like this, had no idea. thanks to jqueryrocks for noticing.

Comment: That's invalid html as well - you can only use any given id # for ONE item on any page.