# jquery fadeIn/Out IE problem - frustrating

Tags: jquery, animation

please please help me someone, i am losing my mind.

i have absolute/relative (tried both) positioned divs all with class of box. on click i want the divs to fade out then the correct one fade in. works fine in all browsers apart from IE 6 and 7 (sometimes 8). they fade out but nothing fades back in. looked all over the net for this type of problem but none help. Please please help.

this is the code

```
$("li#about").click(function(){
   $box.fadeOut(200);
   $("div#about").delay(800).fadeIn(800);
});

$("li#portfolio").click(function(){
    $box.fadeOut(200);
    $("div#portfolio").delay(800).fadeIn(800);
});
```

etc......

what am i missing? demo here - dead link!

Comment: To save you time you should change the selector to the following: `$("#about,#portfolio,#another,#and_antoher").click(/*...*/)` to save you doing it lots of times.

Comment: i understand what you mean but each one needs to fadeIn the corresponding div. so li#about needs to fade in div#about - li#portfolio needs to fade in div#portfolio - if they are grouped like that then when clicked only one and the same div will fade in - right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, do you have multiple HTML tags with the same ID, even though they're different types of tags?  For example, li#about and div#about.  Maybe Internet Explorer would prefer if they had unique IDs?

Comment: you star thank you, did not realise that. now just need to get rid of that horrible text blur when it fades in

Comment: have to say thank you again, over the moon and i learnt something new, jqueryrocks - you rock

Answer (score 1):

I would def be adding achors to your main navigation so that they accessible via keyboard and when JavaScript is turned off. You can then make your script smaller too by doing the following :

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#social">social</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
$("#nav li a").click(function(){
    $box.fadeOut(200);
    $($(this).attr('href')).delay(800).fadeIn(800);
});
```

Comment: You might need to replace(window.hostname, $(this).attr('href')) instaed as I can't remember if IE returns the hostname with the attr ID or not.

Comment: your absolutely right i should be using anchors and i was hoping someone would help me optimise the code, still getting to grips with jquery, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you dont define $box. in IE you need to define it so :

```
var $box = .........
```

you need to do this also with `$nav`

EDIT
The elements in your script that arent working are the once you did not define

Comment: no you didnt: 

`var $name = $("div#name");
$nav = $("div#nav");
$box = $("div.box");`